# How to register with_items and act on conditional check result for each item

Tags: ansible

I'd like to register the contents of bashrc for two users and edit as/if required.  My play is as follows.

```
  - name: Check bashrc
    shell: cat {{ item }}/.bashrc
    register: bashrc
    with_items:
    - "{{ nodepool_home }}"
    - "{{ zuul_home }}"

  - name: Configure bashrc
    shell:
      cmd: |
        cat >> {{ item }}/.bashrc <<EOF
        STUFF
        EOF
    with_items:
    - "{{ nodepool_home }}"
    - "{{ zuul_home }}"
    when: '"STUFF" not in bashrc.stdout'
```

It fails as follows:

```
fatal: [ca-o3lscizuul]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check '\"STUFF\" not in bashrc.stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (\"STUFF\" not in bashrc.stdout): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if \"STUFF\" not in bashrc.stdout %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/openstack-ci/infrastructure-setup/staging/zuul/create-user.yml': line 35, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Configure bashrc\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, if I understand your requirement correctly, you can use the 'lineinfile' or 'blockinfile' modules and save yourself the hassle of testing for the existence of the content:

```
- name: Noddy example data
  set_fact:
    single_line: "STUFF"
    multi_line: |
      STUFF
      STUFF
    profile_dirs:
      - "{{ nodepool_home }}"
      - "{{ zuul_home }}"

- name: Ensure STUFF exists in file
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ item }}/.bashrc"
    line: "{{ single_line }}"
  loop: "{{ profile_dirs }}"

- name: Ensure block of STUFF exists in file
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ item }}/.bashrc"
    block: "{{ multi_line }}"
  loop: "{{ profile_dirs }}"
```

Both modules give a lot more control and you can find their docs here: [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) | [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html)

Comment: It throws error: fatal: [ca-o3lscizuul]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named '{{ profile_dirs }}' in the available lookup plugins"}

Comment: I had to drop the profile_dirs and loop lines and I made some minor alterations and it does as I require. Cheers

Comment: - name: Define bashrc settings
    set_fact:
      multi_line: |
        STUFF
        STUFF

  - name: Configure bashrc
    blockinfile:
      path: "{{ item }}/.bashrc"
      block: "{{ multi_line }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ nodepool_home }}"
    - "{{ zuul_home }}"

Comment: Sorry, I noticed a flaw.  It overwrites previous ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCKs.  Is it possible to avoid this?  I add to bashrc with various plays as system installation progresses.

Comment: Hmm - not sure about your first error. It works fine for me. 'loop' is the new way to do things, so if you are on an older version of Ansible, changing my example to use 'with_items' instead of 'loop' may well fix that. If I understand your last comment, you are using 'blockinfile' more than once per file and so the first instance is overwritten by the second? In which case read up about the 'marker' parameter in the docs.

Comment: That is correct.  I included marker to resolve the overwrite.